# Elm: How can I send extra params to a Msg from "expect" when calling Http.post?

Tags: http, elm

I'm trying to create an APP in Elm at the first time. And I need to interact with a server application using Http.post.

I have Msg type like this:

```
type Msg =
    …
    | Send (String, String)
    | Recv (String, String)
```

and update function is like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        …
        Send (name, data) ->
            (newModel, Http.post
                { url = url
                , body = Http.multipartBody [Http.stringPart "data" data]
                , expect = Http.expectString (Recv name)
                })
        Recv (name, data) -> … -- process data
```

But when I run this, it produces a type mismatch error in Http.post.
So how can I pass name and newData to Msg "Recv" at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type constructor `Recv` is expecting a single argument which is a tuple of string. So essentially `Recv : ( String, String ) -> Msg`.

So when you call `Recv name`, where `name : String`, you will get a type error.

There are two solutions here:

1. You change the definition of `Recv` to be

   ```
   | Recv String String
   ```

   This will now mean that you can partially apply the `Recv` constructor and get back a function `String -> Msg`, which is what `Http.expectString` wants.
2. You change the expect call to get the right shape:

   ```
   , expect = Http.expectString (\body -> Recv ( name, body ))
   ```

   Here you explicitly make the function that `Http.expectString` wants.

Comment: `Recv` is in fact a 'data/value constructor' or a 'variant'. It constructs a value of type `Msg`, it doesn't construct a type. 
`Maybe a` is a type constructor, you can pass it a type as a parameter and it will construct you a type. eg. `Maybe Int`